# Php new cookie overwrites the previous

Tags: php, cookies

In a webshop product page, i am sending the product id with ajax to this php file:

```
    <?php
include_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['product_id']))
{
    $product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_POST['product_id']);

    $cookie_name = "kedvenc_termek";
    $cookie_value = $product_id;

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    echo 'Saved to the favorit products.';

}
?>
```

My problem is, that when i have id-s in the kedvenc_termek cookie, and i want to add another product id as favorit product, the new cookie value will overwrite the value in the cookie.

For example, if i have 179 stored in the cookie, and i add the 180 product id to it, the cookie value will be 180, and not 179,180.

Comment: Instead of SQL-escaping the value then, you should combine the old $_COOKIE and the new value into a list there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array to save the data. You can use PHP's `serialize()` method to save array data as a string, and use `unserialize()` to read the data. Try this:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['product_id']) && is_int($_POST['product_id'])) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    $cookie_name = "kedvenc_termek";
    $data = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
    if(!in_array($product_id, $data)) {
        $data[] = $product_id;
    }
    setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($data), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    echo 'Saved to the favorite products.';    
}
?>
```

Comment: Whit this, i didint get the message, that product is saved.

Comment: You probably got a PHP error, because I'd missed out a parenthesis in the line: `if(!in_array($product_id, $data) {` - it should be `if(!in_array($product_id, $data)) {` - I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see that, but that wasnt the probleme. It doesnt echo out nothing, just an empty alert with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value every time. So you need to append the value, not overwrite it

```
$cookie_name = "kedvenc_termek";
$cookie_value = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    $cookie_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . ',';
}
$cookie_value .= $product_id;

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```